# sql 'select max' query

Tags: sql, select, join

I have a table with name "table_name" approximately like this

```
+----+-----------+
| ID | title     |
| 1  | title 1   |
| 2  | title 2   |
| ...| ......... |
| ...| ......... |
| n  | title n   |
+----+-----------+.
```

And I need a query that returns this result

```
+------+-----------+
| n+1  | title 1   |
| n+1  | title 2   |
| ...  | ......... |
| ...  | ......... |
| n+1  | title n   |
+------+-----------+
```

(n+1 is select max(ID) from table_name)

how can I do that?

Comment: Tag your RDBMS. And by `n+1` in your desired output, do you literally mean every row should have the same higher ID, or that it should have its _old_ ID plus `max(old IDs)`? The latter seems to make a lot more sense, but if you were to explain what you're trying to do, maybe it'd be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a sub-query to the select list:

```
select (select max(ID) + 1 from tablename), title
from tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

Window function

```
SELECT MAX(ID) OVER() + 1, title
FROM table_name
```

Comment: It's ANSI SQL, extension T611, "Elementary OLAP operations". (However, not supported by all dbms products. Stick to Core ANSI SQL to get better compatibility.)

Comment: @jarlh Thanks! It works on MS SQL Server 2008 R2 here, fwiw - providing the result the OP wanted, though without seeing the business logic requirements, I'm not sure why said result would be useful...

Answer (score 1):

You can select this max ID to a variable, and then simply use it in your select:

```
DECLARE @maxId INT = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM [dbo].[table1]);
SELECT @maxId, t.title, t.column2, t.column3 ... from [dbo].[table2] t
```

Answer (score 0):

For Mysql

```
select (1+max(ID)) as ID ,title
from table_name;
```

Comment: This is incorrect. This gives you one result row with ID = n+1 and an arbitrarily chosen title from the table.